# Checkout Error in Braintree Payment

Tags: php, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I'm really stuck with this problem so it would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me.

After I enter amount to pay, choose the way to pay (some credit card for Test from [BraintreeDevelopments](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/credit-cards/testing-go-live/php) ) IT FAILS!

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: nonce in **C:\xampp\htdocs\braintree\checkout.php** on line **5**
>   
>   **Notice**:  Undefined index: amount in **C:\xampp\htdocs\braintree\checkout.php** on line **6**
>   Braintree\Result\Error[errors=[Braintree\Error\ValidationErrorCollection/errors:[( )]], params=transaction=type=sale, amount=, paymentMethodNonce=, options=submitForSettlement=true, message=Amount is required.
>   Cannot determine payment method., creditCardVerification=, transaction=, subscription=, merchantAccount=, verification=]

And this is my checkout.php:

```
<?php
require_once ("braintree_init.php");
require_once 'lib/Braintree.php';

$nonce = $_POST['nonce'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale([
'amount' => $amount,
'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonce,
'options' =>[
    'submitForSettlement'=> True
        ]
]);
echo $result
?>
```

But there are nonce and amount in line 5 and 6 -.- i dont understand why -.-

Comment: The error is saying that `nonce` and `amount` are not specified in the `$_POST` super-global. How are you sending them to `checkout.php`?

Comment: ah, i cant believe where i made mistake o.O I took the wrong variable in Java, at the very beginning, and just sent nothing :( thanks A LOT! It really helped me ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and the issue was that in the `getHeaders()` function, I was putting the wrong params so I wrote it wrong.

I got:

```
params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-**urleooded**");
```

instead of

```
params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-**urlencoded**");
```